# VMWare Ubuntu 16.04 booting to black screen

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtual-machine, vmware, troubleshooting

So I have an ubuntu VM that has most of my programming stuff on it. For some reason, it only seems to boot to a black screen. The ubuntu logo appears and loads, then it just goes to a black screen.
I've seen questions like this that say it gets to the login page, but mine doesn't even get there.
Here's the VMWare log if that helps.
https://dumptext.com/CZhptCuR#

I'm honestly at a loss here.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

For me, this turned out to be a problem with [CPUID masking](https://superuser.com/questions/1300153/vm-with-a-specific-cpu/#1300159) I was using for development purposes.

For some reason, Windows has no problem whatsoever if I force enable some "nonvital" bit. The moment I do with anything based on the Linux kernel though (be it because it actually tries to leverage it, or because nonetheless he doesn't like this mismatch), and not even the recovery console appears.